# Dynamically setting img src tag with c#

Tags: c#, image, dynamic, src

Im trying to set the source of the image tag with C# because the module is not always on the same page with the same path although it is not working.

```
<img id="3ways" src='"<%= ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Images08"].ToString() + "/3ways.png"%>"' border="0" style="padding-bottom:2px;">
```

Comment: Please add details to "although it is not working".

Comment: the image is not showing up on the page.

Comment: what value are you getting back when you read `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Images08"].ToString()` have you tried to step thru the code and put that part outside like `Page_Load` event and see what the value is..? show what the config section looks like to so that we can validate that you are reading the correct AppSettings Value

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I was being nice. If you can not respect that then dont answer... Why are you down voting my question? its a valid question.. What is wrong with you?

Comment: @DJKRAZE I am getting ""

Comment: can you show what the config section looks like please in your app.config file

Comment: You are showing that you are thankful by commenting and voting one answers/updating your post (thank for actually doing that). There is general consensus that tags title in post and all sort of thank you notes [should not be added](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts) to posts. I see good reasons why people voted down - I.e. missing error details like "instead of .... I see ..... and resulting HTML is ..." from the post. If you want I can vote down too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you use runat="server"?  For example:

```
<img id="3ways" runat="server" src="" border="0" style="padding-bottom:2px;">
```

Then on the backend do this:

```
 3ways.Attributes["src"] = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Images08"].ToString() + "/3ways.png"
```

It's cleaner and better seperation of concerns.